# Updating javascript object in a ForEach?

Tags: javascript, foreach, vuex

I have a Object named objectX like this

```
{
    "test": [
      {
        "id": "de6b4d1c-6e04-46a1-908b-9ed5c78e1boc", 
      }, 
      {
        "id": "de6b4d1c-6e04-46a1-908b-9ed5c78e1boc", 
      }, 
      {
        "id": "de6b4d1c-6e04-46a1-908b-9ed5c78e1boc", 
      }, 
      {
        "id": "de6b4d1c-6e04-46a1-908b-9ed5c78e1boc", 
      }, 
      {
        "id": "de6b4d1c-6e04-46a1-908b-9ed5c78e1boc", 
      }, 
      {
        "id": "de6b4d1c-6e04-46a1-908b-9ed5c78e1boc", 
      }
    ], 
}
```

and i want to update the id for all my objects in my test array.

To do that, i was doing

```
    objectX.test.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.id = newId
    })
```

But with my forEach, i have this

```
Error: "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers."
```

Anyone know how can i update my ids without getting error like this ?

Comment: Given that you are using vuex, you probably have to show a more complete example of your code, because you are not actually asking about JavaScript itself but how to do this in the context of that library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't update inside a forEach, because you are updating the copy of the object and not the object itself.
You can instead `map` over your array and return the updated array to another variable:

```js
const objectX = {
  test: [{ name: 'a', id: 4 }, { name: 'b', id: 2 } ],
 };
const newId = 1;
objectX.test = objectX.test.map((obj) => {
  return {
     ...obj,
     id: newId,
    }
 });
 console.log(objectX.test);
```